# How to use drools for this situation

Tags: drools

I've a use-case wherein I've to distribute one set of objects (let's call it as Food objects) among two objects (say Person) satisfying certain conditions (say each Person has minimum energy requirement and say each Food object gives certain defined amount of energy). I would write rules for Person A and Person B. Could someone guide me if this can be achieved using drools. If so, how.

Assume I've following domain objects

```
Person :
  requirement
  List<Food>

Food :
  energy
```

Say I've added Person A and Person B and List of 10 food objects to the knowledgeBase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First answer the following question:
*Can you take a food from the unassigned food list and always decide which Person it should go to, independently of how many other foods that or other persons have already been assigned?*

**If the answer is *yes***, use Drools Expert with rules like

```
when
  $f : Food(unassigned == true)
  FoodLike($p Person, foodLike == $f; $l : likeness)
  not FoodLike(foodLike == $f; likeness > $l)
then
  // assign $f
```

**If the answer is *no***, you got a **bin packing** problem, which is NP-complete. In that case use [Drools Planner](http://www.jboss.org/drools/drools-planner), see [this video of a bin packing problem](http://blog.athico.com/2011/07/real-time-planning-with-drools-planner.html?). So just copy-paste that example (called `cloudbalance`), where the computers would be your persons and the processes would be your food objects.

Comment: How's drools planner better than we sending all possible combinations to the rules one by one ? And ofcourse we can control time limit and max no. of combinations at our end as well like drools planner does.

Comment: Sending all possible combinations to the rules one by one is brute force. Say you have 10 foods and 2 persons, that's `2^10 = 1024` combinations. Say you have 100 foods and 10 persons, that's `10^100= 10000000000000...0000000000000000000` combinations.

Comment: I agree.. but say there's only one possible combination, how will drools planner be helpful. I'm sorry I'm new to drools planner. I don't know how it works.

Comment: Read the Planner manual first :) Depends on how you define things, but in my definitions, a possible solution != a feasible solution. There might only be 1 feasible solution, but if you have more than 1 person there is never only 1 possible solution. Now the thing to understand is that there is no silver bullet to find that 1 feasible solution out of `10^100` possible solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Geoffrey. I just went through the manual. I'll definitely give a try on drools planner as this looks like something what I wanted.

Comment: @Geoffrey De Smet, that's a Googol!